# ARIMA forecast for timeseries is one step ahead

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast timeseries with ARIMA. As you can see from the plot, the forecast is one step ahead of the expected values. I read in some other threads that this behavior is expected but how? How can I synchronize?
[image]

The code I used:

```py
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()

for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history,order=(2, 2, 1))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast(alpha=0.05)
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))

rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predictions))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
# plot
plt.plot(test, color='blue')
plt.plot(predictions, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please share the links to threads being referred in the statement "read in some other threads that this behavior is expected".

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using Python's statsmodel [ARIMA](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html).

There are two options:

1. Change `order=` agrument. The `p`, `d`, or `q` hyperparameters might be causing that result.
2. Manually lag the predictions `predictions = predictions[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your predicted curve (the one colored in red) is FOLLOWING your input (blue) curve. At time t, if blue goes down, then at time t+1, red will go down. You can see this behavior happening twice very clearly in the image once around t = 10 and then second time around t = 20. Also, the magnitude of change in the predicted curve is not as big/low as the input curve.